# How To Add ucwords() in PHP To HTML Form Value?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a basic contact form on my website and I am trying to add the PHP ucwords() function of PHP to the form for the users first_name and last_name fields so they capitalize the first letter correctly. How would I add this to the actual HTML form?

Edit: I want these changes to be applied only after the user submits the form. I don't really care about how the user types it in. I just need someone to actually show me an example.

Like how would I add the PHP ucwords() code to this simple form?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="www.mysite.com" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am assuming I do something like `value='<php echo ucwords() ?>'` but I have no idea how?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean as they type, you'll need Javascript for that. If you want it after they submit the form, you'll just use the POST data for that field and `ucwords` it before you process it.

Comment: You mean you want to apply this to the inputs as the user types, or just when processing the post on the server?

Comment: I only really care about how the data is posted and processed.

Comment: CSS? `text-transform:capitalize;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming short tags are enabled:

```
$firstName = 'Text to go into the form';
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?=ucwords($firstName)?>" />
```

Otherwise as you stated

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo ucwords($firstName); ?>" />
```

Comment: Question has been edited - but is still wrong. I guess the OP meant to ask a javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted to do it without a page refresh, you need to use Javascript. Simplest way would be to add an onkeyup event to the input field and simulate PHP's ucwords functions, which would look something like...

```
function ucwords(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/^([a-z])|\s+([a-z])/g, function ($1) {
        return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

Edit: In response to your edit, if you want to get the value they sent with ucwords applied, all you need to do is `$newVal = ucwords($_POST['fieldName']);`

Comment: I was looking for something more along the lines of: value='<?php if (!empty($first_name)){ echo echo ucwords($first_name); }?>'  Is this possible?

Comment: Other than the double 'echo', looks fine.

Comment: When I use: value='<?php if (!empty($first_name)){ echo ucwords($first_name); }?>'   the first_name value does not change after my form is submitted? The first letter is still small case?

Comment: I'd advise against sticking all that code inside input tag; it's always easier to read and debug if you separate your markup and logic. At the top of the document, I'd do `<?php if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) $first_name = ucwords($_POST['first_name']) ?>`
And then for the input, you can just do `<input name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>">`.

Comment: When you say "at the top of the document", do you mean in the <head> </head> tags or just at the top of the <form>?

Comment: Anywhere. I rarely even combine logic and markup on the same document, but if I'm writing quick and dirty code, I'll usually stick all the PHP above the <html> tag, so it's easy to find.